# Minify and gzip html files in gradle

Tags: gradle, gzip, minify, html-compression

I have lots of js, css, html file in my gradle web project.
I have minified and gzipped my javascript and css files by eriwen's [this](http://eriwen.github.io/gradle-js-plugin/) and [this](http://eriwen.github.io/gradle-css-plugin/) plugins. But couldn't find a way to minify and compress html files in gradle.

It can be done by http server, but I want to minify them once in build time, and reduce http server's job.

Comment: How does minifying HTML files work?